# How to apply a function over a matrix and simultaneously pass parameters?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix e.g. as follows:

```
N = magic(100);
```

I want to apply a function on each column and save its output in another matrix.

Here is my function

```
function z = nikfoo(y, lambda, p)
 m = length(y);
 D = diff(speye(m), 2);
 w = ones(m, 1);
 for it = 1:10
    W = spdiags(w, 0, m, m);
    C = chol(W + lambda * D' * D);
    z = C \ (C' \ (w .* y));
    w = p * (y > z) + (1 - p) * (y < z);
end
```

At first I tried to make a matrix the same size as my data

```
% I take the size of my matrix
[a, b] = size(N);
% make the same size matrix with zeros
corrNiki = zeros(a,b);
```

then I try to do it as follows

```
% I set the lambda as 1000 and p as 0.1
for i = 1:b
   corrNiki(i) = nikfoo(N(i),1000,0.1);
end
```

So now I have these questions

- how can I pass this function with the fixed lammda and p and save the results in corrNiki?
- how can I also pass different values to the Lamda in a range and in P in a range and then save their outputs ?

for example 
Lammda 1000 and P0.1 is saved in data1
Lammda 2000 and P0.01 is saved in data2
.
.
.

Comment: if you want a column, you probably mean `N(i,:)` in your for loop, rigth?

Comment: @Ander Biguri I want the function to be applied on each column of the matrix. let say if the size if 100 columns then the corrNiki will be 100 too

Comment: @Ander Biguri If you want to perform it on one column let say the first one then you can do it Myout = nikifoo(N(:,i),1000,0.1); and it works

Comment: So, then do `corrNiki(:,i) = nikfoo(N(:,i),1000,0.1);`

Comment: @Ander Biguri Yes that works, is it possible to show a plot with some second for each column that this function applies on the matrix ?